# Sheloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 130 words in the section of the Torah that discusses the offerings that a Nazirite brings when his term of Naziriteship expires (Num. 6:13-20). When the leader of the Tribe of Dan brought, among his gifts at the dedication of the Mishkan, a [silver bowl weighing 130 shekels](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/sheloshim-umeya-mi-yodeya/4066#4066), this was what he intended to symbolize.

([Bamidbar Rabbah 14:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&pgnum=108))

Answer (score 4):

Adam when he begat Sheis

Answer (score 4):

The weight in silver of each plate brought by the nesiim at the chanukas hamishkan

Answer (score 3):

Yaakov when he came in front of Paroah

Answer (score 3):

According to the midrash that Yocheved was born as the bnei Yisrael entered Mitzrayim (bein hachomos, Yocheved was 130 when she gave birth to Moshe (210 years in Mitzrayim - 80 years of Moshe when they went out)

Answer (score 3):

According to Rashi, Yitzchak waited 3 years to marry Rivka who was born, acc. to Rashi, at the time of Sara's death, putting the marriage 130 years after Sara's birth.

Answer (score 1):

The Psalm chapter that is said after Yistabah in Aseret Ymei Tshuv

Comment: Nusach Sefard,,,

Answer (score 1):

*Y'hoyada* the *kohen gadol* lived 130 years (I *Divre Hayamim* 24:15).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11864/moses-lived-120-years-and-tradition-says-no-one-can-live-longer-so-why-do-they?lq=1#comment50690_11870

Answer (score 1):

Number of words in *בריך שמיה* (Sort of Tikun for the 130 of Adam)