# Since the Messiah is human, how long will he live?

Tags: messiah, prophecies

The messiah is to be "anointed" and must be versed in the law which mean he would have been alive for a while, and then embarks on his duty by accomplishing the follow:

> - All Jews would be living in Israel (Isa. 11:12, 27:12-13);
> - Israel would also be populated by the resurrected souls who died in previous generations (Isa. 26:19);
> - The Holy Temple would be rebuilt and functioning (Micah 4:1);
> - There would be world-wide peace (Isa. 2:4, 11:6, Micah 4:3);
>
>   and,
> - The entire world would believe in the G-d of Abraham (Isa. 11:9, 40:5; Zephaniah 3:9).

These things are suppose to be ushered in during the Messianic age. Will he be alive to accomplish all these (considering he's human) or is there any mention of his descendants (if he'll marry) or any other thing to prove he'll be alive till all of these are accomplished?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Beveloper and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84497/can-moshiach-die

Comment: @IsraelReader that does not explicitly address the question but talks about the criteria for accepting a Messiah claimant. What happens if he grows old and die before before accomplishing everything detailed. Is there anything to support that he'll miraculously live beyond a "normal" lifespan?

Comment: I'm not sure there are any guarantees, but I might be mistaken; see Wisdom of Solomon 4:9.

Comment: That's the issue with the defence on the accomplishments of the Messiah candidate before his death